# Why this error although my php version is greater than 5

Tags: php, datetime

```
$dateq = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($dateq);
```

**ERROR** -

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_timestamp_get() in /home/Sites
```

PHP version --

```
echo phpversion(); //5.2.17
```

Comment: voted to close:( how could i miss this thing :(

Comment: nothing useful. it will not be asked by programmers that read the documentation about the functions they are using :-/

Comment: @iRaS lol yeah true...thats why i commented how i missed that part ;) voted already to close this

Comment: I think its better if moderator delete this (unable to delete it from my end )

Answer (score 3):

The php version must greater than 5.3.0

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-timestamp-get.php more information.

Comment: Yeas..thx for the reply..just checked it :(

Answer (score 1):

Because date_timestamp_get requires version 5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
    date_timestamp_get requires php version >= 5.3.0
```